# Assign a click event from string to a button

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a string variable called clickEvent which could contain different strings as "buttonAdd_Click" or "buttonSub_Click" or "buttonComp_Click", etc.
Now I need to assign the click event written into the string to a button called buttonCalc.

buttonCalc.click += new RoutedEventHandler(clickEvent) obviously doesn't work because clickEvent is a variable and not a method.

How can I get this thing working?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by reflection:

```
private void AssignClickEvent(string methodName, Button button)
{
    var method = this.GetType().GetMethod(methodName, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    var ev = button.GetType().GetEvent("Click");

    var handler = method.CreateDelegate(typeof(RoutedEventHandler), this);

    ev.AddEventHandler(button, handler);
}
```

Then call it with the name of the method and the button you wish to assign it to:

```
this.AssignClickEvent("ButtonAdd_Click", this.ButtonAdd);
```

That said, you may want to explain why you're doing this, as they're probably an easier way.

Comment: First of all thanks for you answer KooKiz. I can't try your suggestion at the moment but I think that it'll work.

Comment: Concerning the meaning of my request, I need to assign to three favourite buttons properties and methods of other buttons that are in different pages of the app. By tapping and holding the original buttons a context menu appears and this allow me to know which controls have been chosen. Whilst I got name, background, isenabled, etc. I was not able to transfer the event handler (I didn't think about reflection). 

Thanks once again.

Comment: You don't have to use reflection for that. Use delegates.